# Retrofit POST sending the wrong values to server

Tags: java, php, android, retrofit2

I am sending 10 values to a server using Retrofit2. The values I am sending should be (according to the logd):
*getRecommendations* values:

`-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 3, 25, 44.182345, 7.1627383.`

However when I send the values to the server (to a PHP script) with retrofit they are being sent as
`-1, -1 ,0 ,-1 ,-1 ,0 ,25 ,44.182345 , 7.1627383`.
I know this because I'm using a PHP interceptor in Android Studio. Here is what the PHP interceptor shows:
*`maxGradientLo=-1&maxGradientHi=-1&totalDistanceLo=0&totalDistanceHi=-1&altitudeGainLo=-1&altitudeGainHi=-1&numberToRecommend=0&searchWithin=25&currentLatitude=44.182345&currentLongitude=7.1627349853515625`* 
I'm confused as to why this is the case - some of the values have just randomly changed, below I have attached parts of my code.

## getRecommendations() - sends data to server

```
private List<RecommendationJsonResponse> jsonResponse = null;

private void getRecommendations(int maxGradientLo, int maxGradientHi, int totalDistanceLo, int totalDistanceHi, int altitudeGainLo, int altitudeGainHi, int numberToRecommend, int searchWithin, double currentLatitude, double currentLongitude){

        Log.d(Constants.SkiCompanionDebug, "getRecommendations values: " + maxGradientLo + ", "+ maxGradientHi + ", "+ totalDistanceLo + ", "+ totalDistanceHi + ", "+ altitudeGainLo + ", "+ altitudeGainHi + ", "+ numberToRecommend + ", "+ searchWithin);

        RetrofitApiInterface retrofitApiInterface = RetrofitApiClient.getApiClient().create(RetrofitApiInterface.class);

        Call<List<RecommendationJsonResponse>> callRecommendations = retrofitApiInterface.downloadRecommendations(maxGradientLo,  maxGradientHi, totalDistanceLo, totalDistanceHi, altitudeGainLo, altitudeGainHi, numberToRecommend, searchWithin, currentLatitude, currentLongitude);
        callRecommendations.enqueue(new Callback<List<RecommendationJsonResponse>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<RecommendationJsonResponse>> call, Response<List<RecommendationJsonResponse>> response) {
                jsonResponse = response.body();

                //calling helper functions to populate map with ski tracks
                List<List<GeoPoint>> trackList = new ArrayList<>();

                trackList = populateGeoPointLists();
                populateMap(trackList);


            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<RecommendationJsonResponse>> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.d(Constants.SkiCompanionDebug, "onFailure: downloadRecommendations: " + t.getMessage());
            }
        });
    }
```

## Definition of the method in the Retrofit interface

```
@POST("download_recommendations.php")
    @FormUrlEncoded
    Call<List<RecommendationJsonResponse>> downloadRecommendations(@Field("maxGradientLo") int maxGradientLo,
                                         @Field("maxGradientHi") int maxGradientHi,
                                         @Field("totalDistanceLo") int totalDistanceLo,
                                         @Field("totalDistanceHi") int totalDistanceHi,
                                         @Field("altitudeGainLo") int altitudeGainLo,
                                         @Field("altitudeGainHi") int altitudeGainHi,
                                         @Field("numberToRecommend") int numberToRecommend,
                                         @Field("searchWithin") int searchWithin,
                                         @Field("currentLatitude") double currentLatitude,
                                         @Field("currentLongitude") double currentLongitude);
```

## calling getRecommendations()

```
final int[] gradient = new int[2];
final int[] distance = new int[2];
final int[] altitude = new int[2];
final int[] recommendNumber = new int[1];
final int[] searchWithin = new int[1];

//initializing variables
gradient[0] = -1;
gradient[1] = -1;
distance[0] = -1;
distance[1] = -1;
altitude[0] = -1;
altitude[1] = -1;
recommendNumber[0] = 3;
searchWithin[0] = 25;

getRecommendations(gradient[0], gradient[1], distance[0], distance[1], altitude[0], altitude[1], recommendNumber[0], searchWithin[0], 44.182345, 7.1627383);
```

## PHP script where values are posted - note when I echo, the values are wrong, with the same values as the PHP interceptor gave

```
$maxGradientLo = $_POST["maxGradientLo"]; //degrees
$maxGradientHi = $_POST["maxGradientHi"];
$totalDistanceLo = $_POST["totalDistanceLo"]; //kilometers
$totalDistanceHi = $_POST["totalDistanceHi"];
$altitudeGainLo = $_POST["altitudeGainLo"]; //meters
$altitudeGainHi = $_POST["altitudeGainHi"];
$numberToRecommend = $_POST["numberToRecommend"];
$searchWithin = $_POST["searchWithin"]; //number of kilometers track can be from user
$currentLatitude = $_POST["currentLatitude"]; 
$currentLongitude = $_POST["currentLongitude"];

// echo "gradLo: " .$maxGradientLo ." gradHi: " .$maxGradientHi." distLo: " .$totalDistanceLo." distHi: " .$totalDistanceHi." altLo: " .$altitudeGainLo." altHi: " .$altitudeGainHi. " numTorecommend: ".$numberToRecommend;
```

## Extract from OkHttp interceptor

```
02-22 17:12:31.967 25165-25426/skicompanion.skicompanion D/OkHttp: --> POST http://192.168.1.11/ski_companion/download_recommendations.php
02-22 17:12:31.967 25165-25426/skicompanion.skicompanion D/OkHttp: Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
02-22 17:12:31.970 25165-25426/skicompanion.skicompanion D/OkHttp: Content-Length: 204
02-22 17:12:31.971 25165-25426/skicompanion.skicompanion D/OkHttp: maxGradientLo=-1&maxGradientHi=-1&totalDistanceLo=0&totalDistanceHi=-1&altitudeGainLo=-1&altitudeGainHi=-1&numberToRecommend=0&searchWithin=25&currentLatitude=44.182345&currentLongitude=7.1627349853515625
02-22 17:12:31.972 25165-25426/skicompanion.skicompanion D/OkHttp: --> END POST (204-byte body)
02-22 17:12:32.212 25165-25426/skicompanion.skicompanion D/OkHttp: <-- 200 OK http://192.168.1.11/ski_companion/download_recommendations.php (239ms)
02-22 17:12:32.212 25165-25426/skicompanion.skicompanion D/OkHttp: Date: Thu, 22 Feb 2018 17:12:33 GMT
02-22 17:12:32.212 25165-25426/skicompanion.skicompanion D/OkHttp: Server: Apache/2.4.29 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.1.0g PHP/7.2.1
02-22 17:12:32.213 25165-25426/skicompanion.skicompanion D/OkHttp: X-Powered-By: PHP/7.2.1
02-22 17:12:32.213 25165-25426/skicompanion.skicompanion D/OkHttp: Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
02-22 17:12:32.213 25165-25426/skicompanion.skicompanion D/OkHttp: Connection: Keep-Alive
02-22 17:12:32.213 25165-25426/skicompanion.skicompanion D/OkHttp: Transfer-Encoding: chunked
02-22 17:12:32.213 25165-25426/skicompanion.skicompanion D/OkHttp: Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
02-22 17:12:32.405 25165-25426/skicompanion.skicompanion D/OkHttp: [{"track_id":0,"latitude":"44.1831217","longitude":"7.161585"},{"track_id":0,"latitude":"44.183055","longitude":"7.161585"},{"track_id":0,"latitude":"44.183045","longitude":"7.1616433"},{"track_id":0,"latitude":"44.1830083","longitude":"7.16175"},{"track_id":0,"latitude":"44.1829467","longitude":"7.1618833"},{"track_id":0,"latitude":"44.1828983","longitude":"7.1619783"},{"track_id":0,"latitude":"44.18284","longitude":"7.1620783"},{"track_id":0,"latitude":"44.1827917","longitude":"7.1621867"},{"track_id":0,"latitude":"44.1826983","longitude":"7.1621983"},{"track_id":0,"latitude":"44.182595","longitude":"7.1622067"},{"track_id":0,"latitude":"44.1825133","longitude":"7.16229"},{"track_id":0,"latitude":"44.1824533","longitude":"7.1623667"},{"track_id":0,"latitude":"44.182395","longitude":"7.16242"},{"track_id":0,"latitude":"44.1823717","longitude":"7.1623967"},{"track_id":0,"latitude":"44.1823517","longitude":"7.1624283"},{"track_id":0,"latitude":"44.1822717","longitude":"7.162435"},{"track_id":0,"latitude":"44.1821583","longitude":"7.16242"},{"track_id":0,"latitude":"44.1820867","longitude":"7.1624083"},{"track_id":0,"latitude":"44.1820217","longitude":"7.162385"},{"track_id":0,"latitude":"44.182065","longitude":"7.1624167"},{"track_id":0,"latitude":"44.18215","longitude":"7.1624717"},{"track_id":0,"latitude":"44.1822383","longitude":"7.16253"},{"track_id":0,"latitude":"44.18233","longitude":"7.1626317"},{"track_id":0,"latitude":"44.182345","longitude":"7.1627383"},{"track_id":0,"latitude":"44.18233","longitude":"7.1628467"},{"track_id":0,"latitude":"44.1823267","longitude":"7.1629483"},{"track_id":0,"latitude":"44.1823267","longitude":"7.1630267"},{"track_id":0,"latitude":"44.1823117","longitude":"7.163115"},{"track_id":0,"latitude":"44.1822867","longitude":"7.163195"},{"track_id":0,"latitude":"44.1822633","longitude":"7.1633067"},{"track_id":0,"latitude":"44.18226","longitude":"7.163425"},{"track_id":0,"latitude":"44.1822883","longitude":"7.1635117"},{"track_id":0,"latitude":"44.1823217","longitude":"7.163615"},{"track_id":0,"latitude":"44.18236","longitude":"7.1637"},{"track_id":0,"latitude":"44.1823733","longitude":"7.163795"},{"track_id":0,"latitude":"44.182385","longitude":"7.1639"},{"track_id":0,"latitude":"44.1823867","longitude":"7.1640017"},{"track_id":0,"latitude":"44.1823767","longitude":"7.1641033"},{"track_id":0,"latitude":"44.1823733","longitude":"7.1641967"},{"track_id":0,"latitude":"44.1823567","longitude":"7.164295"},{"track_id":0,"latitude":"44.1823367","longitude":"7.16443"},{"track_id":0,"latitude":"44.1823433","longitude":"7.164535"},{"track_id":0,"latitude":"44.18232","longitude":"7.1646767"},{"track_id":0,"latitude":"44.18232","longitude":"7.1647667"},{"track_id":0,"latitude":"44.1823133","longitude":"7.1648767"},{"track_id":0,"latitude":"44.182315","longitude":"7.16499"},{"track_id":0,"latitude":"44.1823067","longitude":"7.1650817"},{"track_id":0,"latitude":"44.1822983","longitude":"7.165165"},{"track_id":0,"latitude":"44.1822983","longitude":"7.1652583"},{"track_id":0,"latitude":"44.1823083","longitude":"7.1653317"},{"track_id":0,"latitude":"44.1823067","longitude":"7.1654133"},{"track_id":0,"latitude":"44.182305","longitude":"7.165505"},{"track_id":0,"latitude":"44.1823067","longitude":"7.16558"},{"track_id":0,"latitude":"44.1822833","longitude":"7.1656767"},{"track_id":0,"latitude":"44.1822733","longitude":"7.165755"},{"track_id":0,"latitude":"44.1822667","longitude":"7.16584"},{"track_id":0,"latitude":"44.182255","longitude":"7.1659233"},{"track_id":0,"latitude":"44.182245","longitude":"7.1659967"},{"track_id":0,"latitude":"44.18225","longitude":"7.166075"},{"track_id":0,"latitude":"44.182245","longitude":"7.16616"},{"track_id":0,"latitude":"44.1822333","longitude":"7.1662483"},{"track_id":0,"latitude":"44.1822383","longitude":"7.1663117"},{"track_id":0,"latitude":"44.1822267","longitude":"7.16642"},{"track_id":0,"latitude":"44.1822117","longitude":"7.1665033"},{"track_id":0,"latitude":"44.1822033","l
02-22 17:12:32.405 25165-25426/skicompanion.skicompanion D/OkHttp: ongitude":"7.16657"},{"track_id":0,"latitude":"44.1821867","longitude":"7.1666433"},{"track_id":0,"latitude":"44.182185","longitude":"7.166705"},{"track_id":0,"latitude":"44.182165","longitude":"7.1668067"},{"track_id":0,"latitude":"44.1821467","longitude":"7.1668367"},{"track_id":0,"latitude":"44.1821417","longitude":"7.166825"},{"track_id":0,"latitude":"44.1821483","longitude":"7.1668017"},{"track_id":0,"latitude":"44.1821517","longitude":"7.1667867"},{"track_id":0,"latitude":"44.1821467","longitude":"7.166755"},{"track_id":0,"latitude":"44.1821567","longitude":"7.1668"},{"track_id":0,"latitude":"44.18216","longitude":"7.1668733"},{"track_id":0,"latitude":"44.1821567","longitude":"7.1669633"},{"track_id":0,"latitude":"44.1821517","longitude":"7.1670583"},{"track_id":0,"latitude":"44.1821483","longitude":"7.1671467"},{"track_id":0,"latitude":"44.1821433","longitude":"7.167245"},{"track_id":0,"latitude":"44.1821317","longitude":"7.167325"},{"track_id":0,"latitude":"44.182115","longitude":"7.1674017"},{"track_id":0,"latitude":"44.18211","longitude":"7.1674533"},{"track_id":0,"latitude":"44.1821033","longitude":"7.16752"},{"track_id":0,"latitude":"44.1821117","longitude":"7.1675633"},{"track_id":0,"latitude":"44.1821183","longitude":"7.16762"},{"track_id":0,"latitude":"44.1821183","longitude":"7.1676817"},{"track_id":0,"latitude":"44.18212","longitude":"7.1677"},{"track_id":0,"latitude":"44.182115","longitude":"7.167735"},{"track_id":0,"latitude":"44.1820967","longitude":"7.1677817"},{"track_id":0,"latitude":"44.1821","longitude":"7.1678133"},{"track_id":0,"latitude":"44.182095","longitude":"7.16784"},{"track_id":0,"latitude":"44.1820867","longitude":"7.1678933"},{"track_id":0,"latitude":"44.1820833","longitude":"7.1679383"},{"track_id":0,"latitude":"44.1820833","longitude":"7.167995"},{"track_id":0,"latitude":"44.1820833","longitude":"7.168045"},{"track_id":0,"latitude":"44.1820783","longitude":"7.1680867"},{"track_id":0,"latitude":"44.182085","longitude":"7.1681433"},{"track_id":0,"latitude":"44.1820933","longitude":"7.1681967"},{"track_id":0,"latitude":"44.1820767","longitude":"7.1682517"},{"track_id":0,"latitude":"44.182085","longitude":"7.16827"},{"track_id":0,"latitude":"44.1821267","longitude":"7.1683067"},{"track_id":0,"latitude":"44.1821683","longitude":"7.1684317"},{"track_id":0,"latitude":"44.1822033","longitude":"7.1685883"},{"track_id":0,"latitude":"44.1822317","longitude":"7.1687067"},{"track_id":0,"latitude":"44.1822617","longitude":"7.16882"},{"track_id":0,"latitude":"44.1822967","longitude":"7.168905"},{"track_id":0,"latitude":"44.18234","longitude":"7.168985"},{"track_id":0,"latitude":"44.1823783","longitude":"7.169075"},{"track_id":0,"latitude":"44.18241","longitude":"7.1691783"},{"track_id":0,"latitude":"44.1824467","longitude":"7.1692817"},{"track_id":0,"latitude":"44.1824733","longitude":"7.1693617"},{"track_id":0,"latitude":"44.1824983","longitude":"7.1694433"},{"track_id":0,"latitude":"44.182535","longitude":"7.1695167"},{"track_id":0,"latitude":"44.18257","longitude":"7.1695967"},{"track_id":0,"latitude":"44.1826017","longitude":"7.169675"},{"track_id":0,"latitude":"44.1826317","longitude":"7.16976"},{"track_id":0,"latitude":"44.1826617","longitude":"7.169845"},{"track_id":0,"latitude":"44.1826917","longitude":"7.1699417"},{"track_id":0,"latitude":"44.18272","longitude":"7.1700417"},{"track_id":0,"latitude":"44.18275","longitude":"7.1701333"},{"track_id":0,"latitude":"44.1827817","longitude":"7.1701833"},{"track_id":1,"latitude":"44.1927117","longitude":"7.1673133"},{"track_id":1,"latitude":"44.1927133","longitude":"7.167285"},{"track_id":1,"latitude":"44.1926983","longitude":"7.1672833"},{"track_id":1,"latitude":"44.1926833","longitude":"7.167265"},{"track_id":1,"latitude":"44.192675","longitude":"7.1672533"},{"track_id":1,"latitude":"44.19266","longitude":"7.16723"},{"track_id":1,"latitude":"44.19264","longitude":"7.1671783"},{"track_id":1,"latitude":"44.19262","longitude":"7.1671083"},{"track_id":1,"l
02-22 17:12:32.406 25165-25426/skicompanion.skicompanion D/OkHttp: atitude":"44.19258","longitude":"7.1670317"},{"track_id":1,"latitude":"44.1925267","longitude":"7.1669217"},{"track_id":1,"latitude":"44.1924933","longitude":"7.1668217"},{"track_id":1,"latitude":"44.1924533","longitude":"7.1667733"},{"track_id":1,"latitude":"44.192395","longitude":"7.1666333"},{"track_id":1,"latitude":"44.1923267","longitude":"7.16649"},{"track_id":1,"latitude":"44.19227","longitude":"7.16636"},{"track_id":1,"latitude":"44.1922167","longitude":"7.16627"},{"track_id":1,"latitude":"44.1921283","longitude":"7.1662083"},{"track_id":1,"latitude":"44.1919817","longitude":"7.16614"},{"track_id":1,"latitude":"44.1918667","longitude":"7.166115"},{"track_id":1,"latitude":"44.1917483","longitude":"7.166105"},{"track_id":1,"latitude":"44.1916233","longitude":"7.1661183"},{"track_id":1,"latitude":"44.1914917","longitude":"7.16613"},{"track_id":1,"latitude":"44.1913883","longitude":"7.1661533"},{"track_id":1,"latitude":"44.1912767","longitude":"7.166145"},{"track_id":1,"latitude":"44.19114","longitude":"7.166065"},{"track_id":1,"latitude":"44.1910617","longitude":"7.1660383"},{"track_id":1,"latitude":"44.19095","longitude":"7.166"},{"track_id":1,"latitude":"44.19086","longitude":"7.165965"},{"track_id":1,"latitude":"44.1907633","longitude":"7.1659317"},{"track_id":1,"latitude":"44.1906383","longitude":"7.1658633"},{"track_id":1,"latitude":"44.190525","longitude":"7.1658017"},{"track_id":1,"latitude":"44.1904033","longitude":"7.1657517"},{"track_id":1,"latitude":"44.1902967","longitude":"7.1657383"},{"track_id":1,"latitude":"44.19019","longitude":"7.16574"},{"track_id":1,"latitude":"44.19007","longitude":"7.1657517"},{"track_id":1,"latitude":"44.1899483","longitude":"7.1657633"},{"track_id":1,"latitude":"44.18984","longitude":"7.165785"},{"track_id":1,"latitude":"44.18971","longitude":"7.165795"},{"track_id":1,"latitude":"44.1895983","longitude":"7.16581"},{"track_id":1,"latitude":"44.18949","longitude":"7.16582"},{"track_id":1,"latitude":"44.1893817","longitude":"7.16583"},{"track_id":1,"latitude":"44.189275","longitude":"7.1658283"},{"track_id":1,"latitude":"44.189175","longitude":"7.16582"},{"track_id":1,"latitude":"44.18906","longitude":"7.1657833"},{"track_id":1,"latitude":"44.1889533","longitude":"7.1657517"},{"track_id":1,"latitude":"44.18884","longitude":"7.1656967"},{"track_id":1,"latitude":"44.18875","longitude":"7.1656267"},{"track_id":1,"latitude":"44.18863","longitude":"7.1656033"},{"track_id":1,"latitude":"44.188515","longitude":"7.1655667"},{"track_id":1,"latitude":"44.1884033","longitude":"7.1655133"},{"track_id":1,"latitude":"44.1883083","longitude":"7.1654633"},{"track_id":1,"latitude":"44.1882117","longitude":"7.1654167"},{"track_id":1,"latitude":"44.1881117","longitude":"7.1653717"},{"track_id":1,"latitude":"44.1879983","longitude":"7.1653217"},{"track_id":1,"latitude":"44.1878983","longitude":"7.1652917"},{"track_id":1,"latitude":"44.1878017","longitude":"7.16528"},{"track_id":1,"latitude":"44.18771","longitude":"7.1652767"},{"track_id":1,"latitude":"44.1876183","longitude":"7.165275"},{"track_id":1,"latitude":"44.18752","longitude":"7.1652733"},{"track_id":1,"latitude":"44.1874083","longitude":"7.16527"},{"track_id":1,"latitude":"44.1873183","longitude":"7.1652817"},{"track_id":1,"latitude":"44.1872233","longitude":"7.1653033"},{"track_id":1,"latitude":"44.1871317","longitude":"7.1653467"},{"track_id":1,"latitude":"44.1870383","longitude":"7.1653917"},{"track_id":1,"latitude":"44.1869517","longitude":"7.1654417"},{"track_id":1,"latitude":"44.1868583","longitude":"7.165495"},{"track_id":1,"latitude":"44.18677","longitude":"7.1655633"},{"track_id":1,"latitude":"44.18669","longitude":"7.1656383"},{"track_id":1,"latitude":"44.186605","longitude":"7.16573"},{"track_id":1,"latitude":"44.186535","longitude":"7.1658217"},{"track_id":1,"latitude":"44.186465","longitude":"7.1659117"},{"track_id":1,"latitude":"44.1863983","longitude":"7.1659867"},{"track_id":1,"latitude":"44.186335","longitude":"7.1661067"},{"tra
02-22 17:12:32.406 25165-25426/skicompanion.skicompanion D/OkHttp: ck_id":1,"latitude":"44.186295","longitude":"7.16623"},{"track_id":1,"latitude":"44.1862533","longitude":"7.1663767"},{"track_id":1,"latitude":"44.1862033","longitude":"7.166505"},{"track_id":1,"latitude":"44.1861433","longitude":"7.1666783"},{"track_id":1,"latitude":"44.1860867","longitude":"7.1668217"},{"track_id":1,"latitude":"44.1860267","longitude":"7.1669667"},{"track_id":1,"latitude":"44.1859567","longitude":"7.167095"},{"track_id":1,"latitude":"44.1858883","longitude":"7.167195"},{"track_id":1,"latitude":"44.1857967","longitude":"7.1673233"},{"track_id":1,"latitude":"44.1857317","longitude":"7.1674467"},{"track_id":1,"latitude":"44.1856667","longitude":"7.16758"},{"track_id":1,"latitude":"44.1855983","longitude":"7.16769"},{"track_id":1,"latitude":"44.185535","longitude":"7.1678017"},{"track_id":1,"latitude":"44.1854533","longitude":"7.1679117"},{"track_id":1,"latitude":"44.1853717","longitude":"7.1680217"},{"track_id":1,"latitude":"44.18529","longitude":"7.1681383"},{"track_id":1,"latitude":"44.1852317","longitude":"7.1682567"},{"track_id":1,"latitude":"44.1851583","longitude":"7.1683567"},{"track_id":1,"latitude":"44.1850833","longitude":"7.1684633"},{"track_id":1,"latitude":"44.1850283","longitude":"7.1685667"},{"track_id":1,"latitude":"44.18496","longitude":"7.168655"},{"track_id":1,"latitude":"44.1848783","longitude":"7.1687267"},{"track_id":1,"latitude":"44.1847933","longitude":"7.1687967"},{"track_id":1,"latitude":"44.1847017","longitude":"7.168855"},{"track_id":1,"latitude":"44.1846083","longitude":"7.1689367"},{"track_id":1,"latitude":"44.1845067","longitude":"7.16901"},{"track_id":1,"latitude":"44.1843967","longitude":"7.1690867"},{"track_id":1,"latitude":"44.1843","longitude":"7.1691717"},{"track_id":1,"latitude":"44.1842217","longitude":"7.1692883"},{"track_id":1,"latitude":"44.1841533","longitude":"7.1694117"},{"track_id":1,"latitude":"44.184075","longitude":"7.1695017"},{"track_id":1,"latitude":"44.1839783","longitude":"7.1695567"},{"track_id":1,"latitude":"44.1838567","longitude":"7.16957"},{"track_id":1,"latitude":"44.1837533","longitude":"7.16956"},{"track_id":1,"latitude":"44.1836517","longitude":"7.1695017"},{"track_id":1,"latitude":"44.1835567","longitude":"7.1694333"},{"track_id":1,"latitude":"44.1834767","longitude":"7.1693583"},{"track_id":1,"latitude":"44.1833983","longitude":"7.1692867"},{"track_id":1,"latitude":"44.1833317","longitude":"7.1692033"},{"track_id":1,"latitude":"44.1832567","longitude":"7.169105"},{"track_id":1,"latitude":"44.1831833","longitude":"7.16896"},{"track_id":1,"latitude":"44.1831233","longitude":"7.1688117"},{"track_id":1,"latitude":"44.1830717","longitude":"7.1686533"},{"track_id":1,"latitude":"44.1830383","longitude":"7.168485"},{"track_id":1,"latitude":"44.183005","longitude":"7.1683067"},{"track_id":1,"latitude":"44.1829817","longitude":"7.1681317"},{"track_id":1,"latitude":"44.1829467","longitude":"7.1679567"},{"track_id":1,"latitude":"44.1829083","longitude":"7.1677867"},{"track_id":1,"latitude":"44.1828867","longitude":"7.16763"},{"track_id":1,"latitude":"44.1828517","longitude":"7.16745"},{"track_id":1,"latitude":"44.1828333","longitude":"7.167305"},{"track_id":1,"latitude":"44.1828083","longitude":"7.16715"},{"track_id":1,"latitude":"44.182785","longitude":"7.1669833"},{"track_id":1,"latitude":"44.1827533","longitude":"7.1667767"},{"track_id":1,"latitude":"44.182725","longitude":"7.1665817"},{"track_id":1,"latitude":"44.1827067","longitude":"7.1664417"},{"track_id":1,"latitude":"44.1826933","longitude":"7.1662883"},{"track_id":1,"latitude":"44.1826817","longitude":"7.1660983"},{"track_id":1,"latitude":"44.182675","longitude":"7.1659433"},{"track_id":1,"latitude":"44.182675","longitude":"7.165785"},{"track_id":1,"latitude":"44.1826867","longitude":"7.165625"},{"track_id":1,"latitude":"44.1827083","longitude":"7.16543"},{"track_id":1,"latitude":"44.1827233","longitude":"7.1652367"},{"track_id":1,"latitude":"44.1827233","longitude":"7.1650733"},{"track_id":1,"latit
02-22 17:12:32.406 25165-25426/skicompanion.skicompanion D/OkHttp: ude":"44.1827367","longitude":"7.1649183"},{"track_id":1,"latitude":"44.182755","longitude":"7.1647617"},{"track_id":1,"latitude":"44.1827617","longitude":"7.164645"},{"track_id":1,"latitude":"44.18278","longitude":"7.16449"},{"track_id":1,"latitude":"44.1827783","longitude":"7.1643717"},{"track_id":1,"latitude":"44.1827717","longitude":"7.1642483"},{"track_id":1,"latitude":"44.1827733","longitude":"7.1640983"},{"track_id":1,"latitude":"44.18277","longitude":"7.1639367"},{"track_id":1,"latitude":"44.1827733","longitude":"7.163795"},{"track_id":1,"latitude":"44.1827633","longitude":"7.1636433"},{"track_id":1,"latitude":"44.1827533","longitude":"7.1634967"},{"track_id":1,"latitude":"44.18275","longitude":"7.16339"},{"track_id":1,"latitude":"44.1827517","longitude":"7.1632383"},{"track_id":1,"latitude":"44.1827583","longitude":"7.16308"},{"track_id":1,"latitude":"44.182775","longitude":"7.1628883"},{"track_id":1,"latitude":"44.18279","longitude":"7.1627317"},{"track_id":1,"latitude":"44.1827933","longitude":"7.162585"},{"track_id":1,"latitude":"44.1828067","longitude":"7.1624017"},{"track_id":1,"latitude":"44.1827967","longitude":"7.1622367"},{"track_id":1,"latitude":"44.1828483","longitude":"7.1621017"},{"track_id":1,"latitude":"44.18292","longitude":"7.16194"}]
02-22 17:12:32.406 25165-25426/skicompanion.skicompanion D/OkHttp: <-- END HTTP (17280-byte body)
```

## extra POJO classes

```
public class RetrofitApiClient {

    public static final String BASE_URL = "http://" + Constants.SERVER_IP + "/ski_companion/";
    public static Retrofit retrofit = null;

    public static Retrofit getApiClient(){
        if(retrofit == null){
            HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
            interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
            OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                    .addInterceptor(interceptor)
                    .retryOnConnectionFailure(true)
                    .connectTimeout(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                    .build();

            retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(BASE_URL).
                    addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()).client(client).build();
        }

        return retrofit;
    }
}
```

Comment: Use Okhttp Interceptor to know what android has been sending. Post your POJO classes.

Comment: I am using Okhttp as the interceptor! I will add a few POJO classes to the question. I have a lot of code so don't want to spam

Comment: Post it so that we can help you more

Comment: Hi SAM, I added in the extract from the okhttp interceptor - and the RetrofitAPIclient. I'm really not sure that any other POJO classes would help in solving the problem :/ are there any other classes you would like me to add? Appreciates the help man!

Comment: @FormUrlEncoded is what you need.

Comment: I have '@FormUrlEncoded' in the definition of downloadRecommendations() in the retrofit interface. Do I need to put '@FormUrlEncoded'  somewhere else also?

Comment: Oops my bad... Lets see what else we got.

Comment: Just to note, I hard-coded the values but result is the same:   Call<List<RecommendationJsonResponse>> callRecommendations = retrofitApiInterface.downloadRecommendations(-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 3, 25, 44.182345, 7.1627383);

Comment: Seems preety good here. However i would recommend you to use Stetho Interceptor which is very good to inspect in google chrome.

Comment: Okay thanks for your help! really annoying/weird error :( I will try stetho

Comment: https://github.com/facebook/stetho

Comment: instead of using retrofit instance as static, use it as a singleton

Comment: Don't mean to be a noob, but could you explain that a little more?

Comment: Is it not already a singleton? I am returning an instance of Retrofit from RetrofitApiClient

Comment: WHAT! IT WORKED! I don't know why!! I've added the simple solution to the top of the question. @SAM could you explain why this worked?

Comment: Maybe it was designed to work as a singleton in a better way :-) Follow Retrofit tutorials from www.futurestud.io

Comment: FutureStud recommends the singleton way

Comment: Don't forget to integrate stetho yo your project. Its cool n superbly informative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to implement the singleton design pattern for Retrofit instance see the following codes:

```
public class ApiClient extends Application {

    private static ApiClient apiClient = null; //singleton Object
    String apiURL = "http://your.url/";


    public static ApiClient getApiClient() {//getter for object
        if (apiClient == null)
            apiClient = new ApiClient();
        return apiClient;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Stetho.initializeWithDefaults(this);
    }

    public Retrofit getClient() {//Retrofit instance
        int myTime = 15;
        OkHttpClient.Builder okHttpBuilder = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .connectTimeout(myTime, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .readTimeout(myTime, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .writeTimeout(myTime, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .addNetworkInterceptor(new StethoInterceptor());

        Retrofit.Builder builder = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(apiURL)
                .client(okHttpBuilder.build())
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create());
        return builder.build();
    }
}
```

Now to use retrofit see the following codes:

```
LoginDTO loginDTO = new LoginDTO(
            etPhno.getText().toString().trim(),
            etPass.getText().toString().trim()
    );

ApiService service = ApiClient.getApiClient().getClient().create(ApiService.class);
Call<LoginResp> call = service.loginAPI(loginDTO);
call.enqueue(new Callback<LoginResp>() {

    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<LoginResp> call, Response<LoginResp> response) {

        LoginResp loginResp = response.body();

    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<LoginResp> call, Throwable t) {

        Toast.makeText(Login.this, "Error here", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```

In the ApiService interface declare the function like this:

```
    @POST("login")
    Call<LoginResp> loginAPI(@Body LoginDTO loginDTO);
```

The LoginDTO class goes like this:

```
public class LoginDTO {
    @SerializedName("log_phno")
    @Expose
    private String user;

    @SerializedName("log_pass")
    @Expose
    private String pass;

    public LoginDTO(String user, String pass) {
        this.user = user;
        this.pass = pass;
    }

    public String getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public String getPass() {
        return pass;
    }
}
```

Now the most important part, go to manifest file and under `<application>` tag put your singleton classname preceded by a dot(.) like this :

```
android:name=".Controller.ApiClient"
```

And atlast to see the magic of Stetho Interceptor, run your app and open Google Chrome and type `chrome://inspect/`

Comment: Thanks for all your help with this problem Sam, you went above and beyond the call of duty!

Comment: Anytime bro. Happy Coding :-)

Comment: See this tutorial by the creator of Retrofit: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t34AQlblSeE

Answer (score 1):

### Answer

This has been an extremely irritating problem and I don't fully understand the solution. If someone could explain why can I not call the method statically- I would really appreciate it. It came down how I was calling the RetrofitApiClient: I was calling getApiClient() statically, but I fixed it by creating a new object of RetrofitApiClient and then calling getApiClient() on that. Solution below:

Old broken code:

```
RetrofitApiInterface retrofitApiInterface = RetrofitApiClient.getApiClient().create(RetrofitApiInterface.class);
```

New working code:

## Getting an instance of RetrofitApiClient

```
RetrofitApiClient retrofitApiClient = RetrofitApiClient.getInstance();
        RetrofitApiInterface retrofitApiInterface = retrofitApiClient.getApiClient().create(RetrofitApiInterface.class);
```

## creating instance in RetrofitApiClient Class

```
private static Retrofit retrofit = null;

    public static RetrofitApiClient instance = null;

    public static RetrofitApiClient getInstance(){
        if(instance == null){
            instance = new RetrofitApiClient();
        }

        return instance;
    }
```